# Use sed as argument for basename

Tags: bash, for, shell-builtin

I have this code so far...

```
for i in {1..200}; do sed '$i,0!d' md5list.txt | grep -a ": "; done
```

I would like to run `basename` for each iteration of the code above, like so:

```
basename $(for i in {1..200}; do sed '$i,0!d' md5list.txt | grep -a ": "; done)
```

How can I do that? What are some keywords, so I can look up similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass the output into `xargs` or into `while`.

```
for i in ...; done | xargs -n 1 basename
```

or

```
for i in ...; done | while read filename; do basename $filename; done
```

Both are about the same.  Xargs would be a little faster, but not as flexible.  You could read the manpage for `xargs(1)` or the man page for `bash`.

Incidentally, your `sed` statements likely won't do whatever you might wish it to do.  You are quoting the variable (`'$i'` instead of `"$i"`), so that would be interpreted by sed as "on the last line, insert a new line ",0!d".  If you wish to get only a single line, then you should probably use `sed -n "${i}p" md5list.txt`.  The `-n` says to not print each line by default and the `p` says to print the buffer.